# Redirected loop when redirecting from www to non www Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I build a website with Google domain on the Nginx server. I want to redirect all links to secure and non www link. For example:

```
http://example.com       ->  https://example.com
http://www.example.com   ->  https://example.com
https://www.example.com  ->  https://example.com
```

Whenever I access to site, the page says `redirected you too many times.`

Here is my `nginx.conf`

```
###### Redirect to secure site
server {
  listen       80;
  listen       [::]:80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

###### Redirect to non www site
server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  server_name www.example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

###### Main config for secure and non www site
server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 http2 ssl;

  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

  root /usr/share/nginx/example.com;
}
```

Comment: Your config looks alright. However the `301 Moved Permanently` redirects are cached by the browser, so he might follow an old redirect. Restart your browser to clear the cache.

Comment: Thank Piotr P. Karwasz but does the domain setting conflict in this case? For example, the www Name should be A type instead of CNAME type?

Comment: Whether `www.example.com` is a `CNAME` or `A` record doesn't matter. If it isn't a problem with your browser (which cached a redirection loop from a previous config), maybe you didn't reload **nginx** after the change. You can debug the problem with `curl -i`.

Comment: Thank you but even when I clear cache, cookies and close browser, the redirect loop still happens... What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's turned out that I have mistake on setting WordPress Address (URL). I have set to `www.example.com` instead of `example.com`. When I correct URL address, everything is fine now.

There is no problem with `nginx.conf`.